# image asset not showing on emulator

Tags: flutter

Im a newbie to flutter and working on a basic screen that will display a dice image

here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const startAli = Alignment.topLeft;
const endAli = Alignment.bottomRight;

class GContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const GContainer(this.colors, {super.key});
  final List<Color> colors;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: colors,
        begin: startAli,
        end: endAli,
      )),
      child: Center(
        child: Image.asset(
          "assets/images/dice-1.png",
          width: 150,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

there are no errors showing it's simply not showing and i did add them image name to my `pubspec.yaml` folder

update: I ran the code on vscode chrome emulator and it does not seem to be able to find my image at all, `error no image or empty`

Comment: go [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images) for adding images using assets add some changes in `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: thanks a lot! i found the solution instantly, it was just with indentation in my pubspec.yaml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this
https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images

1. Make sure these images are available on a relevant path.
2. add path on pubspec.yaml
3. file then try to display image